# angular looses function argument from directive (?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use a directive (note: using jade template engine):

```
file-upload.uploadContainer(complete_function="set_value()")
```

the directive itself:

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
         complete_function: "&completeFunction"
      },
//the rest of the directive
```

This directive uses an UploadService which is angular service.
I need to call complete_function in the controller when upload is finished.

```
uploadService.onUploadComplete(function(event) {
          alert("OK");
          console.log("upload successfully completed");
          url = event.target.response;
          console.log(url);
          $scope.complete_function(url);
        });
```

In the upload service I can see that `url` (which is returning from the server) is valid. Then I proceed calling `$scope.complete_function(url)` which looks like this:

```
$scope.set_value = function(url) {
    console.log("called");
    console.log(url);
```

I know this function gets called because I can see the log "called" (and I have debugged), so the whole chain works like a charm. However, for some reason, `url` is `undefined`in `set_value()`...Why???
Does it have to do with isolated scopes and such? 
How to do it correctly? I tried putting `complete_function="set_value(**url**)` but this didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/11/06/passing-functions-to-angularjs-directives/

Basically need to provide a map of variable(s)...